# WPF Window running in separate thread locks up when clicked

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I'm working with a 3rd party library (Autodesk Revit) whose API requires that all calls take place on the main thread.  So, in order to create a progress window to provide information on the status of running commands, I've been forced to create a window on a new thread. Running the logic in a BackgroundWorker or on any other sort of background thread is unfortunately not an option.

For reference, I'm targeting the .NET Framework version 4.5, and using WPF with an MVVM pattern.

Everything works properly, UNLESS I click anywhere in the window at any point when it's visible.  If I leave the window alone, all properties and both progress bars are correctly updated, and the window closes as expected at the end.

If I click anywhere in the window, it locks up completely - progress bars stop updating, no properties are updated, I can't move it, etc. No exceptions are thrown and there is nothing to indicate that there is an issue. 
Eventually, once the command completes, a 
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException exception is thrown (presumably on the window Close call).
The window remains open (because the call to close it was never received) and becomes updated with the final values that it should have had before closing.  Observing the window in Spy++, I can see that all of the clicks and mouse events that should have taken place while the window was frozen are received all at once.

I hope somebody out there has an idea of what's going on, I'm totally stumped...

Here is the call stack before clicking in the window:
[image: Call Stack Before Click]

And the call stack after clicking in the window:

[image: Call Stack After Click]

Here is the XAML for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.Core.CommandProgressWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:core="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ResizeMode="NoResize" Height="230" Width="310" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp">
<Window.Resources>
    <core:IsIndeterminateToProgressStateConverter x:Key="ProgressStateConverter"/>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo Description="{Binding CurrentAction, Mode=OneWay}"
                 ProgressValue="{Binding OverallProgressZeroToOne, Mode=OneWay}" ProgressState="{Binding ProgressBarIndeterminate, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ProgressStateConverter}}" />
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommandName,Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Grid.Row="0" />

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Current Command:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentCommand, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Model:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModelName, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3">
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Status:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommandStatus, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4">
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Current Action:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentAction, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="5" Height="30" Value="{Binding CurrentActionProgress, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding ActionProgressBarTextVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Current Action Progress:" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentActionNumber, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" / " VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalNumberOfActions, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" Actions Complete" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="6" Height="30" Value="{Binding ModelProgress, Mode=OneWay}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding ProgressBarIndeterminate, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding ProgressBarTextVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Overall Progress:" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentModelNumber, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" / " VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalNumberOfModels, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" Models" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public class CommandProgressViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly string _commandName;
    private string _commandStatus;
    private string _currentAction;
    private int _currentActionNumber;
    private double _currentActionProgress;
    private ActionProgressViewModel _currentActionProgressViewModel;
    private string _currentCommand;
    private int _currentModelNumber;
    private string _modelName;
    private bool _progressBarIndeterminate;
    private bool _progressBarTextVisible;
    private int _totalNumberOfActions;
    private int _totalNumberOfModels;

    public CommandProgressViewModel([NotNull] string commandName)
    {
        _commandName = commandName;
    }

    public bool ActionProgressBarTextVisible { get { return CurrentActionProgressViewModel != null; } }

    [NotNull]
    public string CommandName
    {
        get { return _commandName; }
    }

    [NotNull]
    public string CommandStatus
    {
        get { return _commandStatus; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _commandStatus) return;
            _commandStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    [NotNull]
    public string CurrentAction
    {
        get { return _currentAction; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _currentAction) return;
            _currentAction = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int CurrentActionNumber
    {
        get { return _currentActionNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _currentActionNumber) return;
            _currentActionNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double CurrentActionProgress
    {
        get { return _currentActionProgress; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_currentActionProgress)) return;
            _currentActionProgress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("OverallProgress");
            OnPropertyChanged("OverallProgressZeroToOne");
        }
    }

    [CanBeNull]
    internal ActionProgressViewModel CurrentActionProgressViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentActionProgressViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _currentActionProgressViewModel)) return;
            _currentActionProgressViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ActionProgressBarTextVisible");
            if (value != null)
                value.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    CurrentActionProgress = args.ProgressPercentage;
                    CurrentAction = args.UserState.ToString();
                    TotalNumberOfActions = value.TotalNumberOfActions;
                    CurrentActionNumber = value.CurrentActionNumber;
                };
        }
    }

    [NotNull]
    public string CurrentCommand
    {
        get { return _currentCommand; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _currentCommand) return;
            _currentCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int CurrentModelNumber
    {
        get { return _currentModelNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _currentModelNumber) return;
            _currentModelNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelProgress");
            OnPropertyChanged("OverallProgressZeroToOne");
            OnPropertyChanged("OverallProgress");
        }
    }

    [NotNull]
    public string ModelName
    {
        get { return _modelName; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _modelName) return;
            _modelName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double ModelProgress
    {
        get { return 100.0 * CurrentModelNumber / TotalNumberOfModels; }
    }

    public double OverallProgress
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurrentActionProgressViewModel != null)
            {
                return (100.0 * (CurrentModelNumber - 1) / TotalNumberOfModels)
                    + (1.0 / TotalNumberOfModels) * CurrentActionProgress;
            }

            return ModelProgress;
        }
    }

    public double OverallProgressZeroToOne
    {
        get { return OverallProgress / 100.0; }
    }

    public bool ProgressBarIndeterminate
    {
        get { return _progressBarIndeterminate; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_progressBarIndeterminate)) return;

            _progressBarIndeterminate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool ProgressBarTextVisible
    {
        get { return _progressBarTextVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_progressBarTextVisible)) return;
            _progressBarTextVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int TotalNumberOfActions
    {
        get { return _totalNumberOfActions; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _totalNumberOfActions) return;
            _totalNumberOfActions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int TotalNumberOfModels
    {
        get { return _totalNumberOfModels; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _totalNumberOfModels) return;
            _totalNumberOfModels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelProgress");
            OnPropertyChanged("OverallProgressZeroToOne");
            OnPropertyChanged("OverallProgress");
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase has a simple OnPropertyChanged implementation:

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Code to open the window:

```
using (_commandProgressWindowWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        {
            _commandProgressWindowThread = new Thread((() =>
            {
                Dispatcher currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

                var dispatcherSynchronizationContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(currentDispatcher);

                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(dispatcherSynchronizationContext);

                _commandProgressViewModel = new CommandProgressViewModel(CommandName);

                _commandProgressWindow = new CommandProgressWindow(_commandProgressViewModel);

                //Ensure that the dispatcher is shut down when the window is closed
                _commandProgressWindow.Closed +=
                    (s, e) => currentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

                _commandProgressWindow.Show();

                //Notifies the main thread that the window has been created
                currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<bool>(_commandProgressWindowWaitHandle.Set));

                Dispatcher.Run();
            }));

            //Thread must be STA or an exception is thrown
            _commandProgressWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            _commandProgressWindowThread.IsBackground = true;

            _commandProgressWindowThread.Name = "CommandProgressWindow";

            _commandProgressWindowThread.Start();

            _commandProgressWindowWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
```

And finally, code to close the window:

```
private void CloseCommandProgressWindow()
    {
        _commandProgressWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(_commandProgressWindow.Close);
    }
```

Comment: Windows wont generally recognize a locked main thread until you try to actually do something on it (like click). It looks like you have discovered this the hard way. I would look into finding a way around the API's thread requirement.

Comment: -- or make your Window IsHitTestVisible = false so no one can "click" on it ;)

Comment: I actually didn't know about the IsHitTestVisible property, I was looking for something like that. It's not my ideal solution, as I was hoping to incorporate a cancellation button at some point, but it does solve the locking up problem.  I can probably use the window close button as an alternate to a cancel button. Thanks!